# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException - Attribute

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes

I am coding a C# Winforms application, and one of my objects has an `Attribute` stored as a variable.

When trying to serialize this object using binary serialization, I am getting the following error:

> Additional information: Type
>   'System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute' in Assembly 'System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Is it possible to serialize an object with an `Attribute` object? If so, how can I do this?